# Backup DB on Remote SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-express

I need to create a TSQL script to backup a db on a remote SQL Server Express (2005).  I have a SQL Server 2005 on another box. Not sure how I can run the script from this SQL Server 2005 to do the backup job.

The script is something like this:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [myDB] FROM  DISK = N'C:\Tmp\myDB.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,
   NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
```

Actually, I tried this SQL script on the remote SQL Server Express by using SQL Server Management Studio Express and it runs OK. The reason I ask this question is that I can schedule a job on SQL Server 2005, but I cannot create a schedule job on the remote SQL  Server Express.

Another way, I think, is to create a SQL SP on the SQL Server Express first. Then I'll write a simple console application to connect to the SQL and run the SP as a Windows Scheduled job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to do this by TSQL. SQL Server (also Express) includes a utility called **sqlmaint.exe**, which allows you to perform backup operations on a local or remote SQL server. Simply write a batch file calling sqlmaint with the correct command line parameters ([documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162827%28SQL.90%29.aspx)) and put this batch file in Windows Scheduler.

If you still want to do it by TSQL, SQL Server also contains **osql.exe**, which allows you to execute arbitrary SQL statements on a local or remote server. Again, you can automate it using simple batch files.

EDIT: If you want to call the TSQL script using your own application, it might be helpful to know about your programming language or data access technology of choice.

Comment: Read the doc. What is PlantName or PlantID? How can I define one? My understanding is that a plan defines a list of databases (in my case is for a list of dbs in a remote SQL Server Express.

Comment: You don't need PlanName or PlanID. Have a look a the last example at the very end of the page.

Comment: So, in your case, you would use something like "sqlmaint -S myServer -D myDB -BkUpDB C:\Tmp". Note, however, that the name of the backup file is auto-generated (see BkUpDB on that page). If you need a fixed file name, consider the osql solution.

Comment: Thank you @Heinzi for the information. By using -S -D, I can do one backup from one server. Not sure if I can use Plan to backup a list of dbs from list of servers? By the way, does sqlmaint.exe work for SQL Server Express? The MSDN says it is for SQL Server 2005.

Comment: I can run the exe but I got an error. Anything missing? Here is the er: [Microsoft SQL-DMO (ODBC SQLState: 08001)] Error 0: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()).

Comment: If the exe works locally but not remotely, make sure that the networking is enabled for your SQL Server: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277

Comment: Isn't sqlmaint being killed off in 2005+?  That's what the MSDN docs say.  In 2005 I can run it, but in 2008 it won't even launch.